# iPhone iOS how to compare Class object to another class object?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, class

I have a Class reference defined in one of classes working with:

```
Class _objectClass;

     if([self.objectClass isSubclassOfClass:[NSManagedObject class]])
        {
           //does not get called
        }
```

How can I check what kind of `Class` I'm dealing with?

UPDATE: sorry autocomplete did not show me that  isKindOfClass: was available. I'm testing that now

Comment: You might be looking for the `-isKindOfClass:` method: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSObject_Protocol/Reference/NSObject.html

Comment: For clarity in my answer below...what is objectClass? Is that the name of an actual class? An instance of a class? Please not that semantics suggest classes be named with a capital letter first, and instances with a lowercase. So, MyClass is a class, and instanceOfMyClass is an instance of MyClass.

Comment: Class _objectClass is some kind of a class object reference that RestKit is using to instantiate it's object instances.

Comment: The general rule of thumb is you get a single compiled class object (factory object) that is responsible for creating instances of a class. In addition to my answer below, you could also check if the class responds to a particular selector within NSManagedObject.

Comment: What is the problem with the code you have?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

There are two methods you're interested in:

`isKindOfClass:` asks the receiver if it is a class *or a subclass*, where as `isMemberOfClass:` asks the receiver if it is the class, but *not a subclass*. For instance, let's say you have your `NSManagedObject` subclass called objectClass.

```
 if([self.objectClass isKindOfClass:[NSManagedObject class]]) {
     // This will return YES
 }
 else if ([self.objectClass isMemberOfClass:[NSManagedObject class]]) {
     // This will return NO
 }
```

The first statement returns YES (or true, or 1) because objectClass is a subclass of NSManagedObject. The second statement returns NO (or false, or 0) because while it is a subclass, it is not the class itself.

***UPDATE:*** I'd like to update this answer to bring light to a comment below, which states that this explanation is wrong because the following line of code:

```
if ([self.class isKindOfClass:self.class])
```

would return false. This is correct, it would return false. But this example is wrong. Every class that inherits from NSObject also conforms to the NSObject protocol. Within this protocol is a method called `class` which "returns the class object for the receiver's class". In this case, self.class returns whatever class object self is. However, from the documentation on `isKindOfClass:` -

> Returns a Boolean value that indicates whether the receiver is an
>   instance of given class or an instance of any class that inherits from
>   that class.

thus, sending this message to self.class (which is a class) returns false because it is meant to be sent to **an instance** of a class, not to a class itself.

If you change the example to

```
if([self isKindOfClass:self.class])
```

You will get YES (or true, or 1).

My answer here presumes that self.objectClass is an accessor to an *instance* named objectClass. Sure, it's a terrible name for an instance of a class, but the question was not "how do I name instances of classes".

Comment: Combining the two as above wouldn't achieve that. You would need isKindOfClass:[NSManagedObject class] && isMemberOfClass:[ObjectClass class], assuming self.objectClass is an instance of class called ObjectClass.

Comment: Sure. More than one way to skin a cat. Or program one, for that matter :)

Comment: Your explanation is wrong. For example, `[self.class isKindOfClass:self.class]` would return `NO`, which contradicts to what you are explaining. The `isKindOfClass` is meant to be used to check the class of the instance, not the class itself.

Comment: My explanation is not wrong. Your example is wrong. The class property is part of the NSObject protocol. You're example says if the class that I am (self.class) isKindOfClass the class that I am. But isKindOfClass is meant to be sent to an INSTANCE of a class. self.class returns the class, NOT the instance of one. In my example above, I was under the assumption that self.objectClass was an INSTANCE of some class.

Comment: The question explicitly declares `objectClass_` as a `Class` reference, so even you are right "under your assumption", I don't think your assumption match the question itself.

Comment: if _classObject is a factory object (an object used to facilitate the creation of instances of the class), he should be testing if instances of the class are subclasses of NSManagedObject or not. That's the whole point.

Comment: What the hell is a "factory object (an object used to facilitate the creation of instances of the class)"?  There is such a thing as a "class object" in Objective-C, which is a very specific thing. The type `Class` is a type that can hold a pointer to a class object.

Comment: There are many things wrong in your answer. `self.objectClass` we know is type `Class`, which means it's a pointer to a class object. Calling `isKindOfClass:[NSManagedObject class]` or `isMemberOfClass:[NSManagedObject class]` on a class object will always return NO because a class object is an instance of a metaclass, which inherits from other metaclasses, which ultimately inherits from the root class (`NSObject`). It will never be an instance of `NSManagedObject`. `isSubclassOfClass:` is correct because it is a class method that checks if the thing it is called on is a subclass.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, `[self.objectClass isSubclassOfClass:[NSManagedObject class]]` is correct. If it is false, then that means the class represented by `self.objectClass` is not a subclass of `NSManagedObject`. I don't understand what your problem is, or what you are expecting.